# IndexOutOfRangeException while going through a string

Tags: c#, string, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm making a tool to get used to C#, basically the tool will displays informations of a website but I'll add some funny statistics.

I'm at the part where I grab data between two tags.
I tried using regex and other libraries to do that, but in the end I started doing my own algorithm to get the datas.

I'm used to C algorithms so I did it with loops checking if there is an occurence.

```
while (tag1 < result.Length)
{
    if (result[tag1] == 'h' && result[tag1 + 1] == 'r' && result[tag1 + 2] == 'e' && result[tag1 + 3] == 'f')
    {
        List<char>temp = new List<char>();
        tag1 += 4;
        while (result[tag1] != '>')
            tag1++;
        tag1++;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            richtextbox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + result[tag1 + 7]);
        });
        while (result[tag1] != '<')
        {
            //this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
            //{
            //    richtextbox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + result[tag1]);
            //});
            temp.Add(result[tag1]);
            tag1++;
        }
        string s = string.Join(",", temp.ToArray());
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            richtextbox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + temp);
        });
    }
    tag1++;
}
```

Here is an example HTML line in which I want to grab the "Nickname"

```
<td class="ak-rank"><span class="ak-icon-position">107235</span></td>                  <td class="ak-name"><span class="ak-breed-icon breed12_1"></span><a href="http://www.dofus.com/fr/mmorpg/communaute/annuaires/pages-persos/747884800030-samsung">Samsung</a></td>                  <td class="ak-class">Pandawa</td>                  <td>200</td>                  <td>Many</td>                  <td class="ak-xp-24h">2 884 302 154</td>                  <td class="ak-xp-total">6 027 524 190</td>
```

In that example I want to store "Samsung" in a `List<char>`

My index "tag1" is at its right position before going into the `while (result[tag1] != '<')` loop. And it is supposed to stop once it sees a "<" character.

I've left the debug in the code, it confirms that there is a "<" at `result[tag + 7]`, but when I run it, it says `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Thanks for reading, if I haven't been clear don't hesitate to ask questions!

Comment: Why not to use HtmlAgilityPack and make your life easier?

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, tag1 goes to the full Length of Result in the WHILE loop, yet inside the loop, tag1+7 is used. When tag1 comes within 7 of result.Length, you will get an outOfRangeException because tag1+7 is greater than result.Length. You need to re-think you logic or change:

```
while(tag1 < result.Length)
```

to

```
(tag1 < result.Length-7)
```